# React Location Router doesn't work after changing state in Redux

Tags: redux, react-location

I'm using @tanstack/react-location in React Typescript project + 'react-redux'.

When I change redux auth state (login, logout) I also make my MainNavigation changing. Some Links are added or removed. And when it happens the router stops working.
Updated Links are working, url is changing, but Router isn't responding.
After refresh Router works again.

App.tsx
...

```
<Router
  location={reactLocation}
  routes={appRoutes}
  defaultPendingElement={<Spinner />}
  defaultPendingMs={10}
>
  <MainNavigation />
  <Outlet />
</Router>
```

MainNavigation.tsx

```
    <header className="header">
  <Link to="/" getActiveProps={getActiveProps}>
    <div className="logo">RS Lang</div>
  </Link>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <Link to="/" getActiveProps={getActiveProps}>
          Home
        </Link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link to="/team" getActiveProps={getActiveProps}>
          Team{' '}
        </Link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link to="/textbook" getActiveProps={getActiveProps}>
          Textbook
        </Link>
      </li>
      {isLoggedIn && (
        <li>
          <Link to="/dictionary" getActiveProps={getActiveProps}>
            Dictionary
          </Link>
        </li>
      )}
      <li>
        <Link to="/games" getActiveProps={getActiveProps}>
          Games
        </Link>
      </li>
      {!isLoggedIn && (
        <li>
          <Link to="/auth" getActiveProps={getActiveProps}>
            Login|SignUp
          </Link>
        </li>
      )}
      {isLoggedIn && (
        <li>
          <Link to="/profile" getActiveProps={getActiveProps}>
            Profile {authState.user.name}
          </Link>
        </li>
      )}
      {isLoggedIn && (
        <li>
          <button type="button" onClick={logoutHandler}>
            Logout
          </button>
        </li>
      )}
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

for me the issue was that the definition of the ReactLocation was not in the main.tsx. So I fixed it like so:

main.tsx

```
export const reactLocation = new ReactLocation();

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')!).render(<App />);
```

App.tsx

```
import { reactLocation} from './main.tsx';

export const App = () => {
  return <Router
    location={reactLocation}
    routes={appRoutes}
    defaultPendingElement={<Spinner />}
    defaultPendingMs={10}
  >
    <MainNavigation />
    <Outlet />
  </Router>
}
```

Hope that helps :)
(I was using vite as build tool)